# Error: The multi-part identifier "SOO.IsActive" could not be bound

Tags: marketing-cloud

Did [this](https://code.exacttarget.com/question/more-2500-subscribers) get fixed? Didn't want to do the suggested workaround as I have a large subscriber base (>1M+).

Comment: Not sure, but it was over a year and a half ago. Have you tested it?

Comment: @KellyJAndrews It's not working with version 0.10.0.0 which I'm running. Do you know what the latest version is?

Comment: That version is referring to SOAP, and apparently hasn't changed since 2006. The bug you are referring to, however, has not been corrected. I'm also unaware of any plans on when it will be fixed.

Comment: @KellyJAndrews I added status to the fields coming back and it worked.

Comment: If everything is fixed, make sure you mark this as answered.  Feel free to answer your own question, with what you did, and then check it as the answer.

Comment: @KellyJAndrews Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added status to the fields coming back and it worked.

Comment: Awesome - glad it's indeed working, and not sure why we still have a bug reported.  Appreciate the feed back.

Comment: Any chance you could elaborate on this answer, make it more useful for other folks with the same issue?