# Subscriber ContinueRequest Errors when original request has 2 complex filters

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, soap, php

I am receiving this error message as the result of this code:

"OverallStatus"]=>
  string(70) "Error: The multi-part identifier "LSD.CreatedDate" could not be bound."

Is this a known issue and are there ways around this? I have found another post that is [similar](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23197/error-the-multi-part-identifier-soo-isactive-could-not-be-bound) but not the exact same thing.

```
$client = new ExactTargetSoapClient(WSDL, array('trace'=>1));

        $client->username = $et_user;
        $client->password = $et_pass;

        $rr = new ExactTarget_RetrieveRequest();
        $rr->ObjectType = 'ListSubscriber';

        //Set the properties to return
        $props = array("SubscriberKey", "Status");
        $rr->Properties = $props;

        // //filter based on Status
        $sfp1 = new ExactTarget_SimpleFilterPart();
        $sfp1->Property = 'Status';
        $sfp1->Value = array('Active');
        $sfp1->SimpleOperator = ExactTarget_SimpleOperators::equals;
        $sfp1 = new SoapVar($sfp1, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,'SimpleFilterPart', "http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI");

        //filter based on list id
        $sfp2 = new ExactTarget_SimpleFilterPart();
        $sfp2->Property = 'ListID';
        $sfp2->Value = array($list_id);
        $sfp2->SimpleOperator = ExactTarget_SimpleOperators::equals;
        $sfp2 = new SoapVar($sfp2, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,'SimpleFilterPart', "http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI");

        $cfp1 = new ExactTarget_ComplexFilterPart();
        $cfp1->LeftOperand = $sfp1;
        $cfp1->LogicalOperator = ExactTarget_LogicalOperators::_AND;
        $cfp1->RightOperand = $sfp2;
        $cfp1 = new SoapVar($cfp1, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 'ComplexFilterPart', "http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI");


        // create another simple filter
        $sfp3 = new ExactTarget_SimpleFilterPart();
        $sfp3->Property = 'CreatedDate';
        $sfp3->Value = array(date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', strtotime("-8 days")));
        $sfp3->SimpleOperator = ExactTarget_SimpleOperators::greaterThan;
        $sfp3 = new SoapVar($sfp3, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,'SimpleFilterPart', "http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI");

        // // we want to filter by the date as well. To only grab ones that are a week old.
        $cfp2 = new ExactTarget_ComplexFilterPart();
        $cfp2->LeftOperand = $cfp1;
        $cfp2->LogicalOperator = ExactTarget_LogicalOperators::_AND;
        $cfp2->RightOperand = $sfp3;

        //Execute filter        
        $rr->Filter = new SoapVar($cfp2, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 'ComplexFilterPart', "http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI");
        $rr->Options = NULL;
        $rrm = new ExactTarget_RetrieveRequestMsg();
        $rrm->RetrieveRequest = $rr;      

        $results = $client->Retrieve($rrm);  

while ("MoreDataAvailable" == $results->OverallStatus) {  
            // Email status, date subscribed and date unsubscribed.
            $rr = new ExactTarget_RetrieveRequest();
      $rr->ContinueRequest = $results->RequestID;
      $rrm = new ExactTarget_RetrieveRequestMsg();
      $rrm->RetrieveRequest = $rr;
      $results = null;
      $results = $client->Retrieve($rrm);
```